# Hacer que el bucle imprima todas las líneas y no sólo la última

Tags: batch, .bat

estoy haciendo un script en batch que lo que hace es estandarizar las direcciones MAC almacenadas en un txt, pasando de 1111.1111.1111 a 11:11:11:11:11:11.
Para ello estroy utilizando un bucle *for* que lee las líneas de archivo de texto, quita los `.` para que luego solo haya número y después los vaya imprimiendo intercalando con los `:`. Pero el problema es que sólo imprime la última de las direcciones.
El código es el siguiente:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F %%i IN (%1) DO (
    
    SET parametro=%%i
    
    SET macLimpia=%parametro:.=%
    :: Limpia los puntos

    SET mac=%macLimpia%

    echo %mac:~0,2%:%mac:~2,2%:%mac:~4,2%:%mac:~6,2%:%mac:~8,2%:%mac:~10,2%
    :: Imprime los caracteres de dos en dos intercalando los :
)
```

El archivo .txt que se pasa como parámetro es este:

```
1111.1111.1111
2222.2222.2222
3333.3333.3333
4444.4444.4444
5555.5555.5555
6666.6666.6666
7777.7777.7777
8888.8888.8888
9999.9999.9999
```

Y da como resultado esto último:

```
C:\Users\alexb\Desktop>correctorMac.bat mac.txt
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99
99:99:99:99:99:99

C:\Users\alexb\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras investigar encontré que hay que usar `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, lo que expande las variables, que por lo que entendí hace que las variables obtengan su valor cuando la línea de ejecución llega hasta esa parte del script en lugar de obtener el valor en el momento de análisis. Esto permite a las variables cambiar de valor fácilmente.
Puede que lo entendiera mal pero el script ya está hecho.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%i IN (%1) DO (
    SET argumento=%%i

    SET macLimpia=!argumento:.=!

    SET mac=!macLimpia!

    ECHO !mac:~0,2!:!mac:~2,2!:!mac:~4,2!:!mac:~6,2!:!mac:~8,2!:!mac:~10,2!

)
```

[Más información en una página que encontré](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)